# Physical intuition of solid angle of a closed surface

Tags: differential-geometry, geometry

It is mathematically proven that the solid angle of any closed surface which does not contain the origin, is zero. 
Following the definition of solid angle, the total projection of the surface upon a sphere with radius one is zero. Does it not mean if someone was standing on the sphere, they wouldn't see the surface? Is my intuition right? How does it apply to real life then? I'm sure it is way more complicated than that.
I will be glad for some physical intuition of how is it possible.

Comment: Same question on Math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1866709/

Comment: It is not at all similar, but the reverse. I understand the mathematical derivation, I want physical intuition to what I've said.

Comment: your statement:
It is mathematically proven that the solid angle of any closed surface which does not contain the origin, is zero. is not true, the solid angle of a closed surface is 4pi

Comment: Only if it does contain 0, otherwise you can use Gauss law to prove it is 0.